# Loader CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is an example of a loader animation copied from the w3schools website:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>How To Create A Loader</h2>

<div class="loader"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a similar one on my page with function to hide the loader after seconds of the main page refresh:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#loadingAnimation').addClass('hidden');
  }, 1500);
```

**Now my question is:**
Is there a way to add the animation elements using JavaScript? I mean, when I inspect the page I can change the CSS of the loader which makes it visible, so how can I add the elements on the page using JavaScript and then remove it to make it unchangeable?

```
#loadingAnimation{
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}

#loadingAnimation.hidden{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I'm new to programming :) I need your help and I hope my question is clear!

Comment: Do you want to dynamically remove the loader element from the DOM?

Answer (score 2):

There are some things you can do namely:

1. Add a class into your style that does the animation (Recommended since it requires the least work) and add elements with that class / add the class to elements.
2. Create a new style element with a unique id (somewhat overly complex for something of this scale)
3. [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) - Very hard and easy to go wrong - Basically just for reference

Implementation for 1:
CSS:

```css
.loadingAnimation { /* . notates a class whereas # notates an id */
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

JS:

```js
const loader = document.createElement("div");// Create a new div element
loader.className = "loadingAnimation"; // Add the loadingAnimation class to it
document.getElementById("root").append(loader); // Add it to an element with id root
setTimeout(function() {
    loader.remove(); // Remove the loader
}, 1500);
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add a new `div` inside the first `loader div`? and give it both different styles? Or for example an `img` tag inside a `div` tag as a child...?

Comment: You can create as many elements as you wish and reference them by either id (added as `element.id = "..."` or their variables, for complex cases you can also use CSS selectors with document.querySelector (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of applying the `hidden` class to the loader element you can just simply remove it instead!

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#loadingAnimation').remove();
}, 1500);
```

This will remove it from the DOM and stop people playing with the styling in the dev tools.

I will add though that there's really not a lot you can do to stop people fiddling with websites in their own browsers and it's not that big of an issue.